# Find the type of point D is, wrt $\Delta ABC$

Tags: vectors

> Let $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c, \vec d$ be the position vectors of four points A,B,C,D on a plane such that $(\vec b + \vec c-2\vec d).(\vec b-\vec c)=(\vec c +\vec a -2\vec d).(\vec c-\vec a)=0$, then the point D of triangle is ABC is?

$$((\vec b-\vec d)+\vec (c-\vec d)).(\vec b-\vec c)=0$$

So this says that that sum of vectors $\vec {BD} +\vec {CD}$ is perpendicular to $\vec {BC}$

I don’t know what the sum of those vectors is supposed to be. Assuming that is tan the direction of vector $\vec {DA}$, then D will be the orthocenter of the triangle. But the according to the answer, D is the circumcentre. How is that possible?

Comment: $\frac{b+c}{2}$ is the mid point of $BC$, if $\frac{b+c}{2} - d$ is perpendicular to $BC$, $d$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of side $BC$. Now what triangle center lies on the intersection of perpendicular bisectors of sides of a triangle....

Comment: @achillehui you should have posted it as an answer :) I was writing an answer and then noticed your comment.

Comment: @MathLover You should undelete your answer, sometimes I only want to comment but not answer a question.

Comment: @achillehui the orthocenter?

Comment: @Aditya it should be circumcenter,  $D$ lies on perpendicular bisector of $BC$ implies $DB = DC$. If $D$ also lies on perpendicular bisector of $AC$, then $DA = DC$. This means $D$ is equal distance to all 3 vertices.